# ListBox in TabControl scrolling issue

Tags: wpf, scroll, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have an issue with WPF ListBox in TabControl. ListBox resets it's scrollbar position to 0 when I change tabs. Here is repro code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabs">
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>

_tabs.DataContext = Enumerable.Range(1, 300).ToArray();
```

When the window opens I open the second tab, scroll list somewhere to the middle, return to the first tab and then open the second again. For some reason the list is scrolled to the top.

Why this happens? Have I made some stupid mistake?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (both 3.5 and 4.0). What environment are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of WPF is to unload items which are not visible, which includes unloading TabItems which are not visible. This means when you go back to the tab, the TabItem gets re-loaded, and anything not bound (such as a scroll position) will get reset.

There <strike>was</strike> is a good site [here](http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28) which contains code to extend the TabControl and stop it from destroying it's TabItems when switching tabs<strike>, however the site appears to be down atm</strike>.

Here's the code I use. It initially was from that site, although I've made some changes to it. It preserves the `ContentPresenter` of TabItems when switching tabs, and uses it to redraw the TabItem when you go back to the page. It takes up a bit more memory, however I find it better on performance since the TabItem no longer has to re-create all the controls that were on it.

```cs
// Extended TabControl which saves the displayed item so you don't get the performance hit of 
// unloading and reloading the VisualTree when switching tabs

// Obtained from http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28
// and made a some modifications so it reuses a TabItem's ContentPresenter when doing drag/drop operations

[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ItemsHolder", Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class TabControlEx : System.Windows.Controls.TabControl
{
    // Holds all items, but only marks the current tab's item as visible
    private Panel _itemsHolder = null;

    // Temporaily holds deleted item in case this was a drag/drop operation
    private object _deletedObject = null;

    public TabControlEx()
        : base()
    {
        // this is necessary so that we get the initial databound selected item
        this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// if containers are done, generate the selected item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            UpdateSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get the ItemsHolder and generate any children
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _itemsHolder = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHolder") as Panel;
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// when the items change we remove any generated panel children and add any new ones as necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                _itemsHolder.Children.Clear();

                if (base.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    base.SelectedItem = base.Items[0];
                    UpdateSelectedItem();
                }

                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:

                // Search for recently deleted items caused by a Drag/Drop operation
                if (e.NewItems != null && _deletedObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        if (_deletedObject == item)
                        {
                            // If the new item is the same as the recently deleted one (i.e. a drag/drop event)
                            // then cancel the deletion and reuse the ContentPresenter so it doesn't have to be 
                            // redrawn. We do need to link the presenter to the new item though (using the Tag)
                            ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(_deletedObject);
                            if (cp != null)
                            {
                                int index = _itemsHolder.Children.IndexOf(cp);

                                (_itemsHolder.Children[index] as ContentPresenter).Tag =
                                    (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
                            }
                            _deletedObject = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (e.OldItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                    {

                        _deletedObject = item;

                        // We want to run this at a slightly later priority in case this
                        // is a drag/drop operation so that we can reuse the template
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind,
                            new Action(delegate()
                        {
                            if (_deletedObject != null)
                            {
                                ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(_deletedObject);
                                if (cp != null)
                                {
                                    this._itemsHolder.Children.Remove(cp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ));
                    }
                }

                UpdateSelectedItem();
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Replace not implemented yet");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// update the visible child in the ItemsHolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generate a ContentPresenter for the selected item
    /// </summary>
    void UpdateSelectedItem()
    {
        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // generate a ContentPresenter if necessary
        TabItem item = GetSelectedTabItem();
        if (item != null)
        {
            CreateChildContentPresenter(item);
        }

        // show the right child
        foreach (ContentPresenter child in _itemsHolder.Children)
        {
            child.Visibility = ((child.Tag as TabItem).IsSelected) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// create the child ContentPresenter for the given item (could be data or a TabItem)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ContentPresenter CreateChildContentPresenter(object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);

        if (cp != null)
        {
            return cp;
        }

        // the actual child to be added.  cp.Tag is a reference to the TabItem
        cp = new ContentPresenter();
        cp.Content = (item is TabItem) ? (item as TabItem).Content : item;
        cp.ContentTemplate = this.SelectedContentTemplate;
        cp.ContentTemplateSelector = this.SelectedContentTemplateSelector;
        cp.ContentStringFormat = this.SelectedContentStringFormat;
        cp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        cp.Tag = (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
        _itemsHolder.Children.Add(cp);
        return cp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the CP for the given object.  data could be a TabItem or a piece of data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ContentPresenter FindChildContentPresenter(object data)
    {
        if (data is TabItem)
        {
            data = (data as TabItem).Content;
        }

        if (data == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (ContentPresenter cp in _itemsHolder.Children)
        {
            if (cp.Content == data)
            {
                return cp;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// copied from TabControl; wish it were protected in that class instead of private
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected TabItem GetSelectedTabItem()
    {
        object selectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_deletedObject == selectedItem)
        { 

        }

        TabItem item = selectedItem as TabItem;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(base.SelectedIndex) as TabItem;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

The TabControl template I usually use looks something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TabControlEx_NoHeadersStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:TabControlEx}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type localControls:TabControlEx}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <!-- This is needed to draw TabControls with Bound items -->
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Height="0" Width="0" />
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_ItemsHolder" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried to use your code but nothing changed. The problem is there is no `PART_ItemsHolder` part in the default template (I'm using .NET 4.0, did not check 3.5). Did you use your own template in conjunction with this code?

Comment: @alpha-mouse I added the `TabControl` template I usually use to my answer. I'm fairly sure I've used this class with default TabControls too, however I could be wrong. I have a copy of what I think is the unmodified class, and it uses `PART_ItemsHolder` as well, although its from a few years ago and I think .Net 3.5 was the standard then.

Comment: @alpha-mouse Actually now that I'm looking at my templates and thinking of it, I think having something with `IsItemsHost="True"` was required in your template for this to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that [Eric's site](http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28) is gone again.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer!  Cheers Rachel!  I can't comment on existing posts so have added my own answer.

I found the above managed to solve the problem.  However I also found it necessary to add:

```
    public TabControlEx()
    {
        Loaded += delegate { UpdateSelectedItem(); };
    }
```

to get the initial selected tab to load correctly - the ItemContainerGenerator had no contents and so GetSelectedTabItem failed to return a TabItem.  Presumably this is something to do with rendering which has yet to happen when the template is applied.

I found this problem manifested itself only when binding the ItemsSource and SelectedItem of a tab control - in an application I am working on we have recently switched to using this so we could programmatically switch tabs to do a bit of custom navigation.

The Tab Item contents were originally specified by hand eg:

```
<TabItem Header="blah"> 
    <someControl/>
</TabItem>
```

With that setup changing the selected item was fine (didn't reload tabs on selection) although it was only ever done by wpf.  This seems to suggest that this behaviour can be turned off in the default control but only when not binding to a list of items (although I didn't confirm this to be the case).

Another solutions I attempted were changing the ItemSource binding Mode to OneTime but this did not solve the problem (we aren't using an INotifyCollectionChanged collection here anyway).