# Wpf Dynamic Tabs with RichTextboxes

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I have a system of closable tabs, and each tab has RichTextbox (as a scratchpad). The problem I am having is that whenever I create a new tab it should supposedly create a new RichTextBox, but it overwrites the contents of all the previous RTBs, clearing them all. Can someone tell me why this happens?? It doesn't happen however when I create fixed RTBs (eg create a tab control with 4 tabs and each tab has its own RTB), then everything works fine. but it doesn't work for dynamic tabs?

The code below is from a Usercontrol that is contained within each tab item:

```
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="#FF939393" BorderThickness="26" CornerRadius="26" >
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Border.Effect>           
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Path=TestMessage}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource PageNavigationButton}" Height="52" Width="26" Command="{Binding Path=CMD_SwapLeft}" >
        <Button.RenderTransform >
            <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="13" CenterY="26" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource PageNavigationButton}" Height="52" Width="26" Command="{Binding Path=CMD_SwapRight}" />

    <View:DebtorTabView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.DataContext.MyDataContextVisibility}"  DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDataContext}"  />
    <Grid Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=MyDataContextOtherVisibility}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestMessageTwo}" Height="23" Width="124" Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
```

I haven't done any of the bindings done(which is part of a custom control when I sort out this problem).
Thanks All

Comment: Can you include the code where you create the dynamic tabs as well? Thanks

Comment: SalGad, the are add the same way as in this article by Josh Smith:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because WPF will unload `TabItems` that are not in use, which means if the `Text` property is not bound to anything, it will get reset.

Once you bind your `RichTextBox.Text` property to something in the `DataContext`, it should work fine.

An alternative is to extend the current `TabControl` class so it doesn't destroy its children when you switch tabs. You can find the code for this in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619120/302677) (the site that originally contained the code is not around anymore), and you use the control in the XAML the same way as you would a regular `TabControl`

```
<local:TabControlEx ItemsSource="{Binding OpenTabs}" 
                    SelectedTab="{Binding SelectedTab}" />
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case Thanks :) although the other interesting thing that is happening now is that i create one tab write in the RTB then create a new tab the contents of the RTB in the first tab appears in the RTB of the second tab :/

Comment: Thank You After a "bit" of tweaking I believe I have sorted it :)